# Trying to setup Upnp for a friend so they can use myneigborsushicat. What are tests 7 and 8?

Tags: windows-10, networking, lan, gaming, upnp

My friend and I want to play PPSSPP and use Myneighborsushicat to do it. Doing that requires upnp, so, We both used a program to test our computers. My results were this:

```
TEST 1 - Operating System Support - PASSED
TEST 2 - SSDP Service Running Check - FAILED
TEST 3 - SSDP Service Automatic Check - FAILED
TEST 4 - UPnPHost Service Running Check - FAILED
TEST 5 - UPnPHost Service Automatic Check - FAILED
TEST 6 - UPnP Framework Firewall Exception Check - PASSED
TEST 7 - Adapter #0 - 192.168.174.1 - PASSED
TEST 8 - Get External IP Address (Result: 71.201.67.33) - PASSED
TEST 7 - Adapter #1 - 192.168.75.1 - PASSED
TEST 8 - Get External IP Address (Result: 71.201.67.33) - PASSED
TEST 7 - Adapter #2 - 192.168.56.1 - PASSED
TEST 8 - Get External IP Address (Result: 71.201.67.33) - PASSED
(Plus 2 other adapters)
```

And a quick test of the game with someone who also had sushicat set up showed that it worked. So, 2-5 aren’t required. Then i had my friend try it, and her results  had here fail test 6, so i had her turn on network discovery and she passed it. Now her results are this

```
TEST 1 - Operating System Support - PASSED
TEST 2 - SSDP Service Running Check - FAILED
TEST 3 - SSDP Service Automatic Check - FAILED
TEST 4 - UPnPHost Service Running Check - FAILED
TEST 5 - UPnPHost Service Automatic Check - FAILED
TEST 6 - UPnP Framework Firewall Exception Check - PASSED
TEST 7 - Adapter #0 - 192.168.1.233 - FAILED
TEST 8 - Get External IP Address - FAILED
```

How can she fix test 7 and 8? I know I didn’t fiddle with my router. The only thing i can think of is i have npcap and wincap, some virtual machines that apparently have their own ips, and that’s all off the top of my head.